# How to read JSON data into list

Tags: android, json

I can't seem to get this API to work in Android Studio - here is the link http://diskizone.com/wp-json/sportspress/v2/teams

What I would like to do is read the JSON and add each team to a list in Android Studio, but for some reason it is not working, I'm following a tutorial and have modified the code, this is what I have.

```
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            String teamInfo = jsonObject.getString("0");

            Log.i("Teams ", teamInfo);

            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(teamInfo);

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.i("id", jsonPart.getString("id"));
                Log.i("title", jsonPart.getString("title"));

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is actually returning a `JSONArray` and not a `JSONObject`.
So, try this :

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    try {

        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.i("jsonObject : ", jsonPart.toString());
            Log.i("id", jsonPart.getString("id"));
            Log.i("title", jsonPart.getString("title"));

        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: THanks a mil! Worked first time :)